# Jquery Datatable Print Custom Searched Rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables and the print options in it. I have a problem when the user searches for record in the table's search bar and selects it. After selection when the user removes the entry in the search bar and searches for another record, the previously selected row is unselected? How can I resolve this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search Your Dataa",
    },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'print',
        text: 'Print all',
        exportOptions: {
          modifier: {
            selected: null
          }
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'print',
        text: 'Print selected'
      }
    ],
    select: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am not able to recreate your problem. A row remains selected - even if it is not currently visible, while the user is searching for other data.

Comment: In case it is relevant: When you try to "print selected", then you will only be able to print those **selected** records which have **not** been filtered out by the user's search term. Is that what is actually happening? If so, you can change your "print selected" function to handle that. Or just make sure the users clear the search box before printing.